# SPSS: Assigning a value to macro variable based on data from file B; and that can be called and used later in the program for file A

Tags: spss

I need to be able to firstly calculate the total number of goods (TGC) and bads (TBC). Secondly store the value in a separate dataset (File B) with effectively the one observation with 2 variables (TGC, TBC).
I then need to be able to use the saved variables (TGC and TBC) in calculations on file A.
I have managed to do this in SAS by assigning the values TGC and TBC to macro variables which can then be used later in the program.

How can I do this in SPSS?

For the first part I can create the TGC and TBC values with a simple AGGREGATE. I do not manage however to find a way of creating macro variables to store these values. 
Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions.

1) As @JKP mentioned. Constants can be added as variables to a data file and used afterwards.

2) There is not a straight forward way how value from data can be defined as a macro value. Here is a small example how it can be achieved using WRITE OUT and INCLUDE.

```
do if $casenum=1.
write out="C:\temp\incl.sps"
 /"define !TGC() " TGC " !end.".
end if.
exe.

include "C:\temp\incl.sps".
```

At the end the macro `!TGC` should be defined with value equal to the first value of variable `TGC`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to do, you might be able to use the feature of AGGREGATE that adds the aggregated variables to each case in the input dataset so they would be accessible with the ordinary transformation language.

But incorporating those values directly into syntax is very difficult to do with the macro facility.  It is easy, however, to do this with Python programmability (see the SPSS Community website at www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral), which could read the auxiliary dataset and use its contents to generate appropriate syntax.  The extendedTransforms.py module also available from the site provides a function that allows you to use a secondary dataset as a lookup table.